# Error in playing a sound using ALSA inside LXC container

Tags: sound, alsa, lxc

I am using host `Ubuntu 16.0.4` system to run my lxc container.
I uninstalled `pulseaudio` as I wanted to use ALSA directly.

After uninstalling pulseaudio from the host machine, I was able to play sounds using the command like one below(on host machine):

```
aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Rear_Right.wav
```

Inside the `lxc container`, I have installed `alsa libs` and `alsa utils`.
When I use the same command as above inside the container, I get the following errors:

```
ALSA lib confmisc.c:768:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4248:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4248:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1251:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4248:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:4727:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
aplay: main:654: audio open error: No such file or directory
```

The sound devices inside container are:

```
bash-4.2# ls -al /dev/snd/*
crw-rw---- 1 root   29 116,  5 Nov  1 17:21 /dev/snd/controlC0
crw-rw---- 1 root   29 116,  2 Nov  1 17:21 /dev/snd/controlC1
crw-rw---- 1 root   29 116, 10 Nov  1 17:21 /dev/snd/controlC2
crw-rw---- 1 root   29 116,  9 Nov  1 17:21 /dev/snd/hwC0D0
crw-rw---- 1 root   29 116, 13 Nov  1 17:21 /dev/snd/hwC2D0
crw-rw---- 1 root   29 116,  6 Nov  1 17:21 /dev/snd/pcmC0D3p
crw-rw---- 1 root   29 116,  7 Nov  1 17:21 /dev/snd/pcmC0D7p
crw-rw---- 1 root   29 116,  8 Nov  1 17:21 /dev/snd/pcmC0D8p
crw-rw---- 1 root   29 116,  4 Nov  1 17:21 /dev/snd/pcmC1D0c
crw-rw---- 1 root   29 116,  3 Nov  1 17:27 /dev/snd/pcmC1D0p
crw-rw---- 1 root   29 116, 11 Nov  1 17:21 /dev/snd/pcmC2D3p
crw-rw---- 1 root   29 116, 12 Nov  1 17:21 /dev/snd/pcmC2D7p
crw-rw---- 1 root   29 116,  1 Nov  1 17:21 /dev/snd/seq
crw-rw---- 1 root   29 116, 33 Nov  1 17:21 /dev/snd/timer

/dev/snd/by-id:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  60 Nov  1 17:21 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 360 Nov  1 17:21 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  12 Nov  1 17:21 usb-126c_4.1_amplifier-00 -> ../controlC1

/dev/snd/by-path:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 100 Nov  1 17:21 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 360 Nov  1 17:21 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  12 Nov  1 17:21 pci-0000:00:03.0 -> ../controlC0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  12 Nov  1 17:21 pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:5:1.0 -> ../controlC1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  12 Nov  1 17:21 pci-0000:01:00.1 -> ../controlC2
```

Comment: I guess `aplay -l` does not work either? What is group `29`? Is your user member of that group?

Comment: `29` is `audio` group number on host `Ubuntu` system. And yes, `aplay -l` does not work. it returns with an error: `aplay: device_list:235: no soundcards found...`

Comment: And what is group `29` inside the container (apparently, none), and what about the user inside the container?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to play sounds finally inside the `lxc` container.

First, I have to make sure that lxc device cgroup is enabled for sound devices.
You can do this by adding the following in the container `config` file:

```
#Sound device nodes
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 116:* rwm

lxc.mount.entry = /dev/snd dev/snd none bind,optional,create=dir
```

Next, since I am using `ALSA` on host system to play sounds and want to use the alsa again inside the `lxc container`, make sure that the `alsa` configuration file is copied inside the container.

I copied the alsa config file from host at location `/etc/asound.conf` inside the `lxc` container. The reason for doing this is because the `alsalib` inside the container has to have the same configration to use as the host machine.

After this , I was able to play sounds inside the container. I tested this by running the following :

```
aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Rear_Right.wav
```

Comment: Would you accept you own answer as that what worked for you. That will help others find this solution.